# Laravel Date Time Based Ads System

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have developed a AD System in Laravel But I am stuck showing AD to user.

Here is the process I follow:

**User Create A Ad From Panel**

**Ad field**

- Ad Title
- Ad description
- Ad Start Date
- Ad End Date

Here I am stuck that how to get ad record from database according to the start date and end date.

---

**If the start date and end date only have one day period then this AD come first.**

Comment: Please describe in detail what do you want ?

Comment: from database you wanna search ads that suppose to be shown today which means if today is between start date and enddate show ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is the result what you want:

```
$results = Ad::select(DB::raw('DATEDIFF(`ad_start_date`, `ad_end_date`) AS date_diff, ad.*'))
    ->where('date_diff', '>=', 1)
    ->orderBy('date_diff', 'desc')
    ->get();
```